# iOS Extending UIWindow disabled the root view controller?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiwindow

Team,

I have extended the `UIWindow`, this made my landing view controller (`rootViewController`) disabled i.e., I could not able to interact with it.

`EBaseUIWindow` is the class that has the `UIWindow` as a super class. When I replace the `EBaseUIWindow` with `UIWindow` i could able to interact with the `rootViewController`.

What would be the reason?

```
    self.window = [[EBaseUIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] ;
    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil] ;
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
```

Please suggest?

**Working after my below edit in my code:**

I had a `sendEvent` method overridden in my EBaseUIWindow. In that when I added the below line it started to work.

```
[super sendEvent:event];
```

Thanks to Daij-Djan for the clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without seeing any code of your custom class it's kinda.. guesswork.. there could be many reasons.

BUT

in a way it comes down to 'your window class (or a view or recognizer it adds) consuming the events before they can reach the rootViewController view.

identify places you deal with touches (events in general) and comment them out to see what's causing the issue

Comment: You are right I have overridden sendEvent method. In that i would like to handle the global events. When I remove that method it works. But i need that. What should I do?

Comment: Thanks for your clue. Its working now. I have edited my question with the answer.